# Node.js on windows: express.js app.get routing with files doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

nodejs 0.8 on Windows with express:

Custom routing:

```
app.get("/less/file.less",  function(req, res){
  res.send("XXX");
});
```

If a file is available via URL (for example /less/file.less - public) it propose to download file, instead of returning "XXX" response. I have other behaviour on linux machine.

What can be is wrong? Is it possible to fix?

A

Comment: You are probably using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/less'));` in your app settings (or something like this) **before** `app.use(app.router);`. Make the latter one set earlier.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. But I guess problem is that filesystem is different. What /less/file.less under windows should be something like c:\less\file.less.

Comment: Thanks to freakish! The problem was in app.use(app.router). If you want you may answer I will mark it. Thanks again!